# Entity Framework - Get all records using tableName

Tags: frameworks, entity

I am trying to create a generic "table editor" using Entity Framework.
I would select a table name from a list and would like to get all records for that particular table in a grid.

Is there a way in EF 4.0 to createe a generic method to get a list or records when a table name is passed?

Please note that the method should return a list of mapped entities when a table name is given.

Comment: It may be easier not to us EF for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a generic Dataset and raw, dynamically build SQL!